# PHP sort unique

Tags: php, mongodb

I am completely new to PHP, and I need to retrieve all values ​which ​CONTAIN City. However, this returns more than one document for each city. How do I show the city only once and not multiple times?

All items include City including several items contain the same city, want to be in my dropdown display only unique Cities. As it is now in the code above shows all cities regardless.

```
<?php
$connection = new MongoClient( "" ); // connect to a remote host at a given port
$collection = $connection->value1->value2;
?>

<select name="City" class="form-control">
         <option value="0">Please Select</option>

    <?php $cursor = $collection->find()->sort( array( 'City' => 1 ) );

    foreach ($cursor as $document) {

        echo "<option value='" . $document["City"] . "'>" . $document["City"]                        . "</option>";

    }
    ?>

 </select>
```

Comment: `new MongoClient( "” );` <- You have a weird curly quote here

Comment: What do your documents look like?

Comment: I don't use MongoDB, but I'm guessing you should search for either "GROUP BY" or "DISTINCT" in the docs. Those are the relevant SQL commands and I'm guessing Mongo will follow that lead.

Comment: I know literally nothing about Mongo, but there's a [`disticnt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.distinct.php) function in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
//we will use several temporary values to remove the duplicate City's, values that will be of no use after we're done. thus i want to make a new scope for this.
//php scoping rules suck, and to create a new scope, we need to create a function, iirc.
call_user_func(function() use( &$cursor) { //declare and call a nameless function, and copy $cursor to this function's scope. 
$a1 = array();
$unsetarr = array();
foreach($cursor as $key => $document) {//iterate $cursor
    if (in_array($document["City"], $a1)) { 
    //if we have seen this city before, mark this $cursor entry for deletion. 
    //(we won't delete it right away because modifying the length of the array WHILE iterating it sounds like a bad idea. it certainly would be a bad idea in certain other languages. maybe PHP could handle it, but i don't know.)
        $unsetarr[] = $key;
    }
    $a1[] = $document["City"];
}
foreach($unsetarr as $tounset) {
    //delete all entries that was marked for deletion in the previous loop.
        unset($cursor[$tounset]);
    }
    //maybe $cursor=array_values($cursor); to fix the keys
});
```

Comment: I would suggest breaking this down a bit to explain what is going on. I trust that this would work, but for someone who is new to PHP, it might be more beneficial to know what's going on so they can learn how to tweak it and ultimately be able to write this on their own someday.

Comment: @Alec Deitloff, done.. you're free to improve it if you want :p